# Create table from Array in DB2

Tags: sql, arrays, stored-procedures, for-loop, db2

I need to get a script running that creates tables from an array of numbers I get from a select statement.

Here is what I got so far, however it is not working for some reason and normal PL SQL is not working in DB2 v9.7

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1()
IS
BEGIN 


CREATE TABLE TEMP_YEAR 
   (    YEAR_COLUMN integer
   );


 INSERT INTO temp_year
      ( year_column )
      ( 
        select extract(year from datum) from datetest
      );

     FOR vl AS
    c1 cursor for
        SELECT  year_column FROM temp_year
         DO

         EXEC SQL execute immediate  'create table YEAR_' || year_column 
             || ' (year integer, name varchar2(50));
     END FOR;

drop table temp_year;
   END;
/
```

I first tried it without the procedure but that didn't work either....

Comment: The second line should probably say "as", not "is".  Also, the term, "not working" is too vague.  Are you getting an error or undesireable results?

Comment: I am getting multiple errors. The first one is: (translated from german)

sqlcode: -104

sqlstate: 42601

CREATE TABLE TEMP_YEAR 
   ( YEAR_COLUMN integer
   )
DB21034E  The sql statement is not valid.
SQL0104N  on "ROCEDURE PROC1() AS " follows the unexspected token "BEGIN".  possible tokens are: ":".  LINE NUMBER=3.  SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: This error is in the BEGIN. Start with a more simple stored procedure, with the year value in a variable assigned manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use arrays, you can use Associative arrays. This will ease to write the process that you  want.

For more information, take a look at this excellent article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0710arocena/

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0053499.html

Comment: I don't need to use array... the goal is to be able to create the tables with a name like year_(here a variable value) and take the values from a variable from the select statement. I could only think of doing that with the help of an array. Open for other ideas as well.

Comment: In this case, change your question, or create a new one explain what you want, and what you have done so far. Because your current code is confusing.